# Send through outlook.com when using googleapps

Tags: email, gmail, google-apps, spf, outlook.com

I am currently using google apps for business on my domain. I have however recently switched to a windows phone and would like to start using outlook.com for my email instead of gmail. The problem I am running into is with spf. Is there a way to add an spf record to google apps for business that would allow me to send email with outlook.com and get a pass? I know I could simply disable google apps however my business partner would like to continue using it.

Answer (score 0):

Sure! Just mix both SPFs togther:
Google:
`v=spf1 include:_spf.google.com ~all`

(reference http://goo.gl/nySkg)

Outlook.com:
`v=spf1 include:outlook.com -all`

(reference http://help.outlook.com/140/cc188656.aspx)

To include pass on both:
`v=spf1 include:_spf.google.com include:outlook.com ~all`

Good Luck!